# Amazon SP-API, Blank "name" field for Amazon FBA orders #2049

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

While having access to PII authorization, for Amazon FBA orders, the "name" field is blank for the "getOrderAddress" call. Nowhere does the "name" appear to be visible.
The strange thing is that this information is visible in the csv reports that you do from the Amazon Seller panel.

I don't see anything in the documentation that justifies this behavior and talking to Amazon support is just a waste of time. Is there any maintainer who can tell me something about it?